# Code for extracting CNContactLabels from the IOS contact store

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactstore

I am trying to extract a list of available labels for phone numbers in the IOS contact store so that when the user adds a new number to a contact he/she can select a label from a table list for that number.
I have no problem with retrieving and writing contact numbers but the listing of available labels is eluding me.

What I am really trying to achieve is to extract the array of labels for phone numbers  as in :

```
var phoneNumbers : [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>] = []
```

but I can't find out where to extract values for phoneNumbers.

Comment: I got marked down on this however I still have not found an answer - perhaps my question was poorly phrased - what I meant was:
Getting the list of Standard and custom labels independent of any contact is still something I can't find an answer for.
So all I want to doc is display a list of possible labels for phone  numbers, emails etc ; just as IOS does when you take on a new contact.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check this code for CNLabeledValue, its working for me.

for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
 if let number = phoneNumber.value as? CNPhoneNumber,
  let label = phoneNumber.label {
  let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue.localizedStringForLabel(label)
  print("\(localizedLabel)  \(number.stringValue)")
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems this will get the labels of a contacts existing phone numbers - what  I am trying to find is a list of all labels for phone numbers so that when a user uses my app to take-on a new number he will be presented with a list of possible labels and the option to add a new custom label.
I have downloaded MGContacts (I think written by Apple ) and it does everything except add contacts and labels!\

Comment: Getting the list of Standard and custom labels independently of a contact is still something I can't find an answer for

Answer (score 0):

In the end I extracted a list of label constants from the documentation and did:

```
let arrLab = [CNLabelPhoneNumberHomeFax, CNLabelPhoneNumberMain,CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile,CNLabelPhoneNumberOtherFax, CNLabelPhoneNumberPager, CNLabelPhoneNumberWorkFax,CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone,CNLabelOther ]
    for bod in arrLab {
        let label = CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: bod)
        arr1.append(label)
    }
```

Not ideal because if Apple decides to add a new  constant the app would require maintenance. It would be better to be able to extract the constants directly from the device.
Also, if there are custom labels my code would miss those.